# How to read / write to the Clipboard with JSFL (Flash IDE)

Tags: string, flash, clipboard, read-write, jsfl

Is there a certain JSFL class that can be used to access the Clipboard's data?

I've called this method which copies the newer Motion Object tweens selected on the timeline:

```
timeline.copyMotionAsAS3();
```

But I haven't found anything yet that can return the string copied to the clipboard from this function. If I could just get the string from that method, it'd save me a trip to read it from the clipboard.

Still it would be good to know of a way to access it!

**NOTE: I'm NOT looking for Clipboard access in AS3 at runtime - I'm specifically looking at how this can be done for Flash Extension JSFL scripts (authoring time).**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The motion clipboard is separate. It produces a file that you can read. I've described how to access its contents on this post:
http://ajarproductions.com/blog/2009/03/04/hacking-the-flash-cs4-motion-model-to-create-extensions/

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer, that's going to come-in handy!